# Fill in program

Tags: python

The randint(a,b) function from Python's random module returns a "random" integer in the range from a to b, including both end point.  Fill in the blanks in the function below that creates and returns a random string of 0's and 1s of length n.

```
from random import randint:
def randString01(n):
    _________________
    _________________
    for count in range(n):
        __________________
    return________________
```

(Ed: The `:` at the end of the import statement doesn't belong; it's as presented in the original question, however.)

...so far i found out how to make n into a string of the length of n(so a string of n n's) I want to know where would the randint apply?
So far i have

```
from random import randint
def randString01(num): 
    x = str() 
    count = num 
    while count >0: 
        if randint(0,1) == 0: 
            append.x(0)   
        else: 
            append.x(1) 
        count -= 1
    x=str(x) 
    return x
```

but it doesnt work.  What should I fix?

Comment: Show us your code that you've tried, not your teacher's code. What does this code have anything to do with making 'n into a string of length n'?

Comment: @gnibbler: AFAICT, the problem was presented by the OP as stated in their own homework sheet. I don't think it should be amended.

Comment: Will people please stop down-voting? The OP hasn't asked to be spoon-fed.

Comment: Well in the end i want a random string of 0's and 1's that has a lenght of n characters, so i thought i would have to make a program that first makes n into a string of n characters and then use the randint operation to convert the characters into 0s and 1s

Comment: @Marcelo, I didn't add the import, I just indented it as part of the code block

Comment: @gnibbler: Sorry, my mistake. I've added the statement back in.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is homework, I won't give you the answer, but here are some leading questions:

- How would you use `randint(a,b)` to give you either 0 or 1?
- How do you convert an integer to a string?
- How can you build up a string with a for loop?

If you can answer those, you've solved the problem.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me.  Can you tell me if i am on the right start.  For the first blank i put n=n*str(n) to give me the n n's

Comment: and for the record its not homework its a in-class project but none of my classmates are able to figure it out so i turned to this helpful website

Comment: Ronnie: Not quite - you do not want a string of N "n"s, you want a string of N "0" or "1"s. The N is simply a count, not something that must literally be there.

Comment: I see...thank you i believe the psuedocode from above is what i needed. The only difference its that the wording in which sage uses it is different. for example while count is greater than zero would be while count >0:.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's clearly classwork, here's some pseudo-code to start with:

```
define randString01(num):
    set str to ""
    count = num
    while count is greater than zero:
        if randint(0,1) is zero:
            append "0" to str
        else:
            append "1" to str
        subtract one from count
    return str
```

Your string of `n` occurences of the character `n` will not help here by the way. It will either give you a zero-sized "0" string or a one-sized "1" string. In other words, all ones.

---

Okay, what you have in your comment seems okay (at least in structure):

```
from random import randint
def randString01(num):
    x = str()                       ## <-- ???
    count = num
    while count > 0:
        if randint(0,1) == 0:
            append.x(0)             ## <-- ???
        else:
            append.x(1)             ## <-- ???
        count -= 1
    x = str(x)                      ## <-- ???
    return x
```

but I'm just a little uncertain about your `str()` and `append()` lines. Since you've *done* the bulk of the work, here are my minor changes to get this going under Python:

```
from random import randint
def randString01(num):
    x = ""
    count = num
    while count > 0:
        if randint(0,1) == 0:
            x = x + "0"
        else:
            x = x + "1"
        count -= 1
    return x

print randString01(7)               ## And add these to call the function.
print randString01(7)
print randString01(9)
print randString01(9)
```

This outputs:

```
1011000
1010011
110001000
110101001
```

Comment: Hey thank you i greatly appreciate it, my entire class is having difficulty answering theses questions

Comment: By any chance do you know how to use the append operator in sage?

Comment: `x = "abc"`, `x = x + "def"` will give you `x` of `"abcdef"` in Python. I haven't use sage but it looks like it's Pythonesque.

Comment: I believe so, so so far i have from random import randint def randString01(num): x = str() count = num while count >0: if randint(0,1) == 0: append.x(0) else: append.x(1) count -= 1 x=str(x) return x

but it doesnt work. do you see anything i should fix?

Comment: I put it on the original question but it came out in one block.

Comment: @Ronnie, you have to leave a blank line before code and ensure you indent each line by at least 4 spaces. I fixed that up for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have to use the exact syntax above, this can be accomplished with 1 line of code.

concepts:

string.join takes an iterable
you can create an iterable of random string by inlining the for loop in to a list comprehension

the resulting code is as follows.

```
''.join([str(random.randint(0,1)) for i in range(n)])
```

Comment: Hmm when I use it in sage i get a syntax error:'function' object has no attribute 'randint'